# Finding a subset of the data in which two variables are independent

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, cross-correlation

I have a dataset of ~400 subjects. For each subject, I have about 18 variables (V1...V18), all of those continuous and measured at the same timepoint.

A paper I'm working on would benefit from showing that one of those variables (say V1) has a significant correlation with one of three other variables (say V2, V3, or V4) – all of these are measuring different aspects of the same illness. And I have found some significant correlations between the pairs (V1–V2, V1–V3, V1–V4). However, I have another variable, say V5, that is more strongly correlated to all of them (V1–V4). When I correct (linearly) for V5, the correlations between V1–(V2/V3/V4) is no longer significant/there.

So at this point, any critic could say that the V1 is correlated to V5, V5 is correlated to V2/3/4, and that I can't make the point I want to make. However, I have reason to believe that subgroups of the subjects (more susceptible to the illness), will show strong correlation between V1 and V2–4 that is independent of V5. *Is there any way to find these subgroups?*

I would like to find some partition(s), A < Vx < B, in which there is a significant correlation between V1 and V2/V3/V4, that I can show is independent of V5. Alternatively, if there's a way to quantify how much of the correlation between V1 and V2–4 is due to correlation between V1–V5 and how much is independent, that would be a good solution as well.

I have been reading a lot about two-way ANOVA, thinking about doing it between V1 as rows, V5 as columns, and one of V2–4 as outcome. But even if I do this (which would take significant effort, since I couldn't find a simple Python implementation), I'm not sure if it would advance me towards my goals. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a potential mediation problem. Might be worth performing the usual mediation analyses if V5 would make theoretical sense as a mediator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess some procedure of blind search could be designed in order to test correlations in various partitions of your sample. Assume that you indeed find a sub-sample in which what you think must hold, appears to hold. What keeps me from attributing it to small-sample variability and reject it?

Nothing, except if the subjects in this subgroup have a set of characteristics that "separates" them from the other subjects, and justifies viewing them as a meaningful subset of the data.

And in your question, it appears that you do have a theoretical argument about your issue :"if subjects are more susceptible to the illness, then $V_2, V_3, V_4$ stop being uncorrelated with $V_1$ conditional on $V_5$."

So, instead of activating a blind mechanical search, wouldn't it be more valid (and probably less computationally intensive), to start by constructing a metric for the "susceptibility to illness" degree, then separate your sample according to this criterion, and then calculate, on the sub-samples acquired thus, correlations etc?

I cannot say whether you will get the results you think you should get, but I am certain that the results from such a procedure would be considered more scientifically acceptable.

On another aspect of your question, the Law of Total Covariance states that

$$\operatorname{Cov}(V_1,V_i)=\operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Cov}(V_1,V_i \mid V_5)\right]+\operatorname{Cov}\left[\operatorname{E}(V_1\mid V_5),\operatorname{E}(V_i\mid V_5)\right],\;\; i=2,3,4$$

The first component of the right-hand-side can be thought of as the "part" of covariance between $V_1$ and $V_i$ that is "independent of $V_5$" (in the sense of "what remains after conditioning on $V_5$").

**ADDENDUM**

To apply the Law of Total Covariance, one can calculate the *second* term of the right hand side.
1) Regress $V_1 = a+bV_5+u_{1,5}$ and obtain $\hat V_1 = \operatorname{\hat E}(V_1\mid V_5) $ (not the residuals)
2) Regress $V_i = c+dV_5+u_{i,5}$ and obtain $\hat V_i = \operatorname{\hat E}(V_i\mid V_5)$ (not the residuals)
3) Calculate  the covariance of these two series

4) Subtract what you found in step 3) from $\operatorname{\hat Cov}(V_1,V_i)$ as it is calculated from the sample. The result is an estimate of the "independent from $V_5$" part of covariance between $V_1$ and $V_i$

Comment: Yes, it would be more valid / interesting to find such a metric and divide the samples intelligently. However, the evidence I have concerning subgroups come from a different experiment, and I can't deduce anything from it on the variables in question (that's why it would be so awesome to find something here - as these are two independent experiments).

Comment: Regarding what you wrote on the law of total covariance - pardon my newbiness, can you direct me in how to actually apply this to the data?

Comment: You write in your question: "when I correct linearly for V5 etc etc". How did you actually implement this "linear correction"?

Comment: `def CorrectVectorBy(tocorrect, correctby):
    a, b, r, p, _ = linregress(correctby, tocorrect)
    return tocorrect - (a * correctby + b)`

Comment: I am not quick in deciphering man-machine language. Does this mean that you regressed, say $V_2 = a + bV_5$ and then calculated the correlation coefficient $Corr (V_1, \hat U_{2,5})$, where $\hat U_{2,5}$ are the residuals from said regression??

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I apologize, I interpreted "actually" in you previous comment literally.

Comment: No problem. Just added a little something to my answer.